# Java dependency is absent in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, maven, manifest

I have some problems with some of my dependencies, declared in pom file dependencyManagement section: dependency is not included to MANIFEST.MF file. This dependency is used in web project in  section. However, there is no related declaration about this dependency in MANIFEST and deployed app fails with exception. How to guarantee adding this dependency to MANIFEST file?
Thanks.

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Comment: Can you show the pom file?

Comment: please check your war's WEB-INF/lib folder for the jar that contains the java class represented in your el expression.

Answer (score 1):

Maven does not put dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF file. If you have web project which means having a war file all dependencies will be packaged into the war file. Furthermore it's not needed to put the dependencies into the MANIFEST.MF file.
If you really like having the dependencies into your MANIFEST.MF file you have to configure the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html) like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

If you define a dependency only in dependencyManagement it will not be a real dependency. This is only a definition of the version to be used.
To make a dependency really be used to your project you must define the dependency in dependencies.